# why pycharm gives a wrong condition check?

Tags: python

I have a string to be read from a file, there are cases that the readline() will return a blank line and I need to check that, please see the screenshot below and it would be appreciated if anyone can explain to me why it gives a wrong result:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, line='\n', why the expression's evaluation result is False?

There for sure are alternative way to check the blank line, but I am just very curiously wanting to know why my this script is not working.

Thank you.

Thanks.

Comment: If you need to test against a blank line use `line == ""` not `line == "\n"`. The newline character is not a blank string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input file most likely contains some nasty characters, like ["zero width space"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm) or ["invisible separator"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm). You can output these if you print (or evaluate) `repr(line)`:

```
with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(u"\n")
    f.write(u"\u200B\n")  # zero width space
    f.write(u"\u2063\n")  # invisible separator
    f.write(u"\n")


with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(repr(line))
```

If you debug the above, you will be able to replicate your behaviour for lines 2 and 3, but not for lines 1 and 4. Note that these characters are not visible in most fonts (they do not take up any space!), and simply printing/displaying them (as does the hovering in the debugger) will thus not reveal that they are even there.

In the "evaluate expression" dialog in PyCharm, simple evaluate "`repr(line)`" to see what's really in it.

Comment: Thank you. Like you said, the first line read in does contain some invisible characters: 0d0a0d0a, which is actually two blank lines

Answer (score 0):

`'\n'` is not a blank line. `""` is. So you can check `if line == "":` or `if not line:`. And if you read from file python will remove `\n` from the line. So if it is empty (has only new line character) it will return an empty string.

Comment: no use, actually I was using `line=="" `, it just returns the wrong result

Comment: f = open('2014ips.txt')
for line in f:
    if line=="":
        continue

Comment: the file to be read might cause this issue: the file's first two lines are empty, means: 0d0a0d0a at its beginning, so len(line) = 4